# How to solve $y" -2y' -3y = 9x e^x$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve the following differential equations?
$$
y'' - 2 y' - 3y = 9x e^x
$$

The method of undetermined coefficients says, if the RHS of a standard non-homogenous linear equation is a linear combination of a polynomial $p(x)$, $e^x$, $\sin x$, and $\cos x$ then we can assume the solution to be
$$
y = A p(x) + B e^x + C \sin x + D \cos x 
$$

where $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ are to be determined.

But the equation given to us, is not a linear combination of a polynomial and an exponential function. What solution to assume?

P.S. : Users might say "there are hundreds of resources available teaching how to handle that type of equations", but I'm an auto-didact and the resources I'm using doesn't teach the methods for doing it.

Comment: That's a pretty odd version of undetermined coefficients technique. Begin by solving the homogeneous equation and get $Ae^{3x}+Be^{-x}$. For  a particular integral I'd be looking at $(ax+b)e^x$ and hoping that worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the RHS is of type $p(x)e^{ax}$ then one solution is of type $q(x)e^{ax}$.
In this case, a solution would be (by setting $q(x)=c x$)
$$
y = -\frac{9}{4}xe^x.
$$
The homogeneous part can be solved with your previous method.

Also, see [here](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Calculus/Book%3A_Calculus_(OpenStax)/17%3A_Second-Order_Differential_Equations/17.02%3A_Nonhomogeneous_Linear_Equations#:%7E:text=complementary%20equation%20for%20the%20nonhomogeneous,form%20of%20the%20particular%20solution) a list of starting guesses for different RHS types of non-homogeneous linear equations.

Comment: +1 To the OP, in general, setting $q(x) = cx + d$ is the better choice. However, in this case, because $e^x$ is a solution to the homogeneous part, we know that the $de^x$ in $(cx + d)e^x$ will be eliminated by the left hand side, so there is no need to include it. If the left hand side were different, e.g. $y'' - 2y' - 8y$, then $e^x$ would no longer be a homogeneous solution, so you would have to set $q(x) = cx + d$, otherwise you may find that the method fails.

Comment: @TheoBendit I, every time, assumed the solution to be of same degree polynomial when RHS is a polynomial of some degree. But in solving $$y” + y’ = x^2 +2x$$ when I assumed the solution to be $y= Ax^2 + Bx + C$, I got $y_p= x^2 -2x + C$ which is wrong. Why the technique didn’t work?

Comment: Indeed I excluded the constant part of $q(x)$ because I knew it was equal to $0$ and I wanted to simplify the exposition. Be careful, $e^x$ is not a solution of the homogeneous equation! But you are correct, the right way to approach is to consider $q(x)=cx+d$ and find $c,d$ which satisfy the non-homogeneous equaiton. You will see that $d=0$.

Comment: @DeltaPsi You need to consider $y$ to be a polynomial of degree $3$. As you know, the derivative scrapes one degree of the polynomial. If $y$ is of degree $2$, then $y'+y''$ will be of degree $1$. If $y$ is of degree $3$, then $y'+y''$ will be of degree $2$.

Comment: @Kolja On the contrary, you will find that $d$ will cancel out! As in, you won't be able to deduce that $d = 0$, you'll just find that it doesn't appear in the equation you're solving. This makes sense: we can add any multiple of $e^x$ (or any other term from the homogeneous equation) to any particular solution to get another particular solution.

Comment: @DeltaPsi Yes, Kolja right. This is the unfortunate quirk in the system for determining particular solutions, to do with when "some part" of the particular solution is eliminated by the homogeneous part. The irony is, this "some part" is the constant term, and there isn't even a constant term on the right hand side! But we kinda need to perceive a constant there for the sake of closure with respect to differentiation (in that, when differentiating $x$ and $x^2$ terms repeatedly, we eventually get constants). Yes, it's annoying, but there's no way to match $x^2$ terms without it.

Comment: @DeltaPsi You could consider asking a separate question about it.

Comment: @TheoBendit If you set $y=e^x$ then $y'' -2y' -3y = -4e^x \not= 0$, so there is no cancelling out.

Comment: @Kolja Oh, right! Whoops. I think I confused it with $y'' + 2y' - 3y$.